# Connecting IBM Domino admin with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to re-certify multiple users in IBM Domino admin and was curious if it can be done through VBA where I can write all the names in an excel sheet and it can re-certify all the IDs.
I can go into Lotus notes with this code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
```

But this is not what I want. I need to reach the below window and then re-certify option

[image]

Comment: add the Lotus Notes objects at : VBE->tools->references ->look through the Lotus Domino objects, maybe there is something there

Comment: @Daghan :  I got  'Lotus Domino objects' but what is the use?

Comment: You can use the "NotesAdministrationProcess" - class and its "[RecertifyUser](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_RECERTIFYUSER_METHOD_ADMINP.html)" method... Almost all Classes from LotusScript can be used in VBA...

Comment: But what do you need this for? In admin- client this is 3 clicks and entering a new expiration date... even opening excel will last longer....

Comment: If you have lots of users to do, or a moderate amount that you would have to do every week or month, and someone is giving you the list of usernames already typed into an Excel sheet, it could be worth it. Of course, I'd probably do it in LotusScript instead of VBA myself, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz : So what you are saying is I can do that in Lotus script? 
And yes, I have lots of users to do. Do you have any script ready? I am not aware of the methods and functions used in Lotus script

Comment: @TorstenLink : I have more than 1000 users. So just 3 clicks will take 3000 clicks for 1000 usrs :p

Comment: No, as you can select all of that 1000 users at once (Ctrl-A) and then it will still be three clicks....and if you choose the same end date for all of them its 3 clicks once a year...

Comment: @TorstenLink Makes sense. I will try and get back to you

Comment: If you have OU- certifiers, then you need to select the users for each ou. Then it will be slightly more clicks...

Comment: @TorstenLink : Yes Torsten, we have around 50-80 certifiers :p

Comment: Okay... Yes, I'm saying that you can (probably) do it in LotusScript. If you can do it in Excel, you can definitely do it in LotusScript. But no, I've never done this. I have no code. I have no knowledge of any limitations on it, what really works, etc. If I had code, it would meet my requirements for my process of identifying the users, etc., which may not be the same as yours.

Comment: Torsten has already linked to the method that you would need for recertification. That's not a complete solution, obviously. If you have no knowledge of LotusScript and the Notes/Domino classes, you would have to learn more than that. If you are already comfortable in VBA and Excel, and you have a way to get the usernames into a spreadsheet, that's your best route. Less to learn that way, but you'll still have to learn at least the basics of how to create a session, etc.

Comment: I would not use Excel at all... The information about expiry is in every person document in the Domino directory. Writing an agent that creates AdminP- documents to recertify users is not that hard at all. I did this for one of my customers once and the relevant code for that part is about 200 lines at most... The challenging part is to approve these requests as you need either access to the certifiers and their passwords or have a Domino CA set up and the rights to programmatically use that... In Excel it will almost the same code as stated before...